# How to generate random INT that cannot be a value in a List<int>?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime

I'm trying to do the following.

Let's say I have a List, and I want to generate a new int in a specific range, but the value cannot be already defined in the List.

```
List<int> PredefinedIntsList = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 };
Random rnd = new Random();
int NewRandomValue = rnd.Next(0, 10);
```

rnd.Next (obviously) comes up with 1, 3, 4, 8 or 9. But I ONLY want it to return 2, 5, 6, 7 or 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: It is a round-about way to ask "How do I randomly shuffle numbers".  A very common question.  In this case, just randomly pick an element from a list with 10 integers, minus the ones you don't want, and remove it from the list so it cannot be picked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, LINQ is your friend:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RandomTest()
{
    var except = new[] {1, 2, 3, 5};
    GetRandomExcept(1, 5, except).Should().Be(4);
}

private static int GetRandomExcept(int minValue, int maxValue, IEnumerable<int> except)
{
    return GetRandoms(minValue, maxValue).Except(except).First();
}

private static IEnumerable<int> GetRandoms(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    var random = new Random();
    while (true) yield return random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
}
```

Just keep in mind that you never should call `GetRandoms().ToArray()` or `.Max()` or `.OrderBy()` and so on, because you will get an endless loop and generate randoms forever.

What you can do though, is call `GetRandoms().Take(10).ToArray()` to get the next 10 random integers in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try examining if you can use the contains() method of List class... Simple solution would be to just generate values and checking contains and rejecting values that are already in the List until you get a value that is not. Also it might be more appropriate to use the Set Class because a set can not contain two elements that are equal.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do sample from other set. Lets say **P** is your predefinedIntsList and A is {1,2...9}.
You need to create a list, **N = A-P**. You will randomly sample from this set of numbers.  It can be written more elegantly I suppose but see below example.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> predefinedIntsList = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<int> newIntsList = new List<int>();

        int upperBound = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < upperBound; i++)
        {
            if (!predefinedIntsList.Contains(i))
            {
                newIntsList.Add(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int newRandomValueIndex = rnd.Next(0, newIntsList.Count);
            int newRandomValue = newIntsList[newRandomValueIndex];
            Console.WriteLine(newRandomValue);

        }

    }
}
```

Output

```
2
0
6
7
5
5
5
7
0
7
6
6
5
5
5
0
6
7
0
7
```

Answer (score 0):

> rnd.Next (obviously) comes up with 1, 3, 4, 8 or 9. But I ONLY want it
>   to return 2, 5, 6, 7 or 10.

Obviously not, it will return value that is either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9 :P. If you're looking to include 10, and not 0, you want `.Next(1, 11)`

There are two choices that can work: either try generating values until you succeed, or if the range is small enough, generate the range, mark elemens that can't be picked, and sort them to last ones, and then pick random between [0..possibleToPickElementsCount]

The first approach would look something like this:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static int Next(this Random random, 
        int minInclusive, 
        int maxExclusive, 
        IList<int> values)
    {

        // this will crash if values contains
        // duplicate values.
        var dic = values.ToDictionary(val => val);

        // this can go into forever loop,
        // think about this a bit.
        for(;;){
            var randomNumber= random.Next(minInclusive, maxExclusive);
            if(!dic.ContainsKey(randomNumber))
                return randomNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

The second approach is this, however it's only to give you an idea:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    class NormalizedPair
    {
        public int Value {get;set;}
        public PairStatus Status {get;set;}

        public NormalizedPair(int value){
            Value = value;
        }

        public enum PairStatus {
            Free,
            NotFree
        }
    }

    private static Random _internalRandom = new Random();

    public static int Next(this Random random, 
        int minInclusive, 
        int maxExclusive, 
        IList<int> values)
    {
        var elements = maxExclusive - minInclusive;
        var normalizedArr  = new NormalizedPair[elements];

        var normalizedMinInclusive = 0;
        var normalizedMaxExclusive = maxExclusive - minInclusive;
        var normalizedValues = values
                .Select(x => x - minInclusive)
                .ToList();

        for(var j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            normalizedArr[j] = new NormalizedPair(j){
                Status = NormalizedPair.PairStatus.Free
            };
        }

        foreach(var val in normalizedValues)
            normalizedArr[val].Status = NormalizedPair.PairStatus.NotFree;

        return  normalizedArr
                    .Where(y => y.Status == NormalizedPair.PairStatus.Free) // take only free elements
                    .OrderBy(y => _internalRandom.Next()) // shuffle the free elements
                    .Select(y => y.Value + minInclusive) // project correct values
                    .First(); // pick first.
    }
}
```

Or, if you're fan of sets:

```
public static int Next2(this Random random, 
    int minInclusive, 
    int maxExclusive, 
    IList<int> values)
{
    var rangeSet  = new HashSet<int>(
                        Enumerable.Range(
                            minInclusive,
                            maxExclusive - minInclusive));
    // remove gibberish                                 
    rangeSet.ExceptWith(new HashSet<int>(values));


    // this can be swapped out with
    // yates shuffle algorithm
    return rangeSet.OrderBy(x => _internalRandom.Next())
                    .First();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write logic to determine whether the random number has already been selected I prefer to generate  a second list with the items in a random order.

That is easy to do with LINQ

```
var originalList = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 };
Random rnd = new Random();
var secondList = originalList.OrderBy(x=>rnd.NextDouble());
```

The call to `rnd.NextDouble` returns a random seed that is used by the `OrderBy` method to sort each int value.

When I need to run thought the randomized items more than once, with a new sort order each time I walk the list, I will use a `Queue` to store the items.  Then dequeue the items as needed.  When the queue is empty it's time to refill.

```
private Queue<int> _randomizedItems;
  private void  RandomTest()
  {
    var originalList = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 8, 9 };
    Random rnd = new Random();

    var temp = originalList.OrderBy(r=>rnd.NextDouble());
    _randomizedItems = new Queue<int>(temp);

    while (_randomizedItems.Count >0) 
    {
      MessageBox.Show(_randomizedItems.Dequeue().ToString());
    }
  }
```